# How do I pass second parameter from CMD (%2) into a PowerShell variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a file called `test.bat`.

It contains a call to a PowerShell script (Process.ps1) as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -File %1
```

where `%1` is the name of the PowerShell file I would pass on the command line.

So essentially, it looks like this on the command line:

```
e:> test.bat Process.ps1
```

Right now the script runs as it should. However, I need to pass a second argument (%2) in the batch file (test.bat) so it would look like this:

```
Powershell.exe -File %1 %2
```

%1 is Process.ps1

%2 will be some cube name (i.e. CUBE1)

So on CMD it would look like this eventually:

```
e:> test.bat Process.ps1 CUBE1
```

Now, how can I pass that second argument (CUBE1) into a variable (`$CUBE`) declared in the PowerShell script (Process.ps1)?

I researched around the forums, but I can't find an example like my own case.

This may be something very simple I'm missing out on, but I am new to PowerShell/batch scripting so I can't quite put my finger on the answer.

Comment: ``param($CUBE)``

Comment: Wait thts it? So param parses the %2 argument?

Comment: @PetSerAl so if there was %3 and %4, how would param be modified to know to set which variable to which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. The first is the use of the `Parameter` declarations:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(mandatory)]
    [String]
    $first,
    [Parameter(mandatory)]
    [String]
    $second
)
Write-Output "First argument: " $first
Write-Output "First argument: " $second
```

The second is the built-in `$args` variable:

```
Write-Output "First argument: " $args[0]
Write-Output "Second argument: " $args[1]
```

Comment: i see, so $args is a built in variable?

Comment: Yes, $args is a built in variable.

Comment: thanks! It worked perfectly.. I accepted your answer :)